# Karate - editing xml while running the test case

Tags: karate

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request>
    <head>
        <session-id>none</session-id>
    </head>
    <service name="test">
        <function name="testFunc">
            <guids>
                <guid>#guid#</guid>
                <guid>#guid#</guid>
            </guids>
        </function>
    </service>
</request>
```

I have 2 test cases:

1. i want to test with single guid.
2. I want to test with 2 guids.

I created 2 separate xml for both the test cases and it worked.
The question here is how can i use a common xml?
Also i tried using remove but how do i remove single guid from the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called "embedded expressions" in Karate. Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Example:

```
* def guids = <guids><guid>one</guid><guid>two</guid></guids>
* def body = <root>#(guids)</root>
```

Also refer this file, it has a lot of other examples and ideas for XML data-driven tests: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature).