# How to set WSS timetolive in karate feature

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

Please help me set WSS timetolive using karate for SOAP request. This can be able to set in SOAPUI tool, how to set in karate tool

Answer (score 0):

Karate has a simple approach, you just have to create XML as plain-text. If you can't do that, Karate is not the right tool for you.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432866/143475

EDIT - I am not an expert on this, but it sounds like you just need to generate date formats such as `2017-01-09T23:56:42.000Z` and then use normal Karate techniques for data-driven testing.

For ideas on date-handling, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938480/143475

Comment: Can you please answer for the below url https://stackoverflow.com/a/69219483/16930460

Comment: @user16930460 I edited the answer here, and if that does not help - I repeat that you should look for another framework - because Karate does not support what you want